# Impact of <em> tag on landingpage experience or SEO

Tags: seo, google-ads, landing-page

the company I'm working at, didn't had someone who knew a lot about SEO, also the google ads account had grown very lonely. I'm an apprentice and don't know that much either, but I'm determined to learn.
I already improved a lot of stuff on google ads, however I also need to improve the landing pages
design and content wise.

The issue I'm having right now is that I´ve read on some occasions that the  tag is important for SEO. Here on SE a post from 2015, said it isn't important.
If that's still the case, i would like to know when to use and how to not overuse it.
Like I'm very tempted to use it on important words. Sadly the text would look like patchwork then.

```
<div class="c-flexitem">
  <img src="/pics/icon/e-5w92w-07-grww-000.svg" alt="Gear" width="100" height="100">
      <div>
           <h4>Suitable for industry</h4>
           <p>
           With <em>DIN rail</em>, Power-over-Ethernet <em>(PoE)</em> or 
           <em>24V-Supply</em> and all needed certificates, the rule.box is ideal to be used as an 
           <em>Edge-Computer</em> for <em>industrial purposes</em>.
           </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

I know speaking URLs are important but my company has 4000 Websites and the guidelines for saving files is older than the modern internet. It will happen eventually just not yet.
If you guys have any other tips on improving my first landing page feel free to do so.

I´m looking to improve the landing page experience factor from google ads as it is below average.
It could also be though that the factor didn't update yet as this new landing page has only been online for 2 weeks now.

Comment: You need to find up to date SEO information.   `<em>` was thought to be important for SEO 15 years ago, but that isn't the case now.

Comment: To @StephenOstermiller's point, you can find some useful tips under https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions.  There's lots of good content about SEO there.